# SED command giving carriage return

Tags: sed, csv

I have a problem with a SED command
I need to replace the @ character with a string and append a string to a column in a csv file

So

```
foo@example.com
```

Would become

```
foo_X_example.com@newdomain.com
```

I’m using the following sed command

```
sed -i .bak -E 's/([^,\n\“]*)@([^,\n\“]*)/\1_X_\2@newdomain.com/' Test.csv
```

But I have a new line break somewhere in the command like so

```
foo_X_exxample.com
@newdomain.com
```

Can anyone advise where the error in my SED command is?

Comment: You might get something like this if the CSV file is in Windows (CR/LF) format. If this is the case add `\r` to the not-to-match characters.

Comment: Yes Im using a Mac with a Windows file saved in the CSV format

Comment: Have tried `sed -i .bak -E 's/([^,\r\n\“]*)@([^,\r\n\“]*)/\1_X_\2@newdomain.com/' Test.csv`? That should solve it. Let me know it does, and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Thanks AFH - tried that but still the same as previously

Comment: I tried it by creating a file with `foo@example.com` followed by CR/LF, and it works OK, while without the `\r` in the search fields it retained the return character before the `@`. Your other option is to use the `dos2unix` utility on the file before passing it to `sed`, but unlike the first method this loses the Windows file format. I'm using Ubuntu Linux, but it's possible that, although Linux-based, your Mac OS uses a different end-line sequence.

Comment: @AFH your answer is correct, please post it together with a sample file before and after being altered by the `sed` command.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your original file `test.csv` is Windows-formatted, with return (`0x0d` or `\r`) and line feed (`0x0a` or`\n`) for each new-line. Your `sed` search pattern does not exclude `\r` so this will be retained in the second matched field and output *before* the appended text.

So your original command:

```
sed -i .bak -E 's/([^,\n\“]*)@([^,\n\“]*)/\1_X_\2@newdomain.com/' Test.csv
```

gives the output file (using `od -c` to see the control characters):

```
0000000   f   o   o   _   X   _   e   x   a   m   p   l   e   .   c   o
0000020   m  \r   @   n   e   w   d   o   m   a   i   n   .   c   o   m
0000040  \n
```

If you add `\r` to the excluded characters:

```
sed -i .bak -E 's/([^,\r\n\“]*)@([^,\r\n\“]*)/\1_X_\2@newdomain.com/' Test.csv
```

then the original new-line sequence is maintained:

```
0000000   f   o   o   _   X   _   e   x   a   m   p   l   e   .   c   o
0000020   m   @   n   e   w   d   o   m   a   i   n   .   c   o   m  \r
0000040  \n
```

Note that you don't need `\r` or `\n` in the first matching field, as this form of `sed` command will match only within single lines and not through new-lines.